# How can I find the index number of a form field where multiple fields have the same name?

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML form with an array of input fields all with the same name.
I can access any field by indexing it.  If one of these fields gets focus and
I have an onFocus function, how can that function tell which field got focus?

```
<form name="formName"> 
<input type=text name=fieldName onFocus="see(this)"> 
<input type=text name=fieldName onFocus="see(this)"> 
<input type=text name=fieldName onFocus="see(this)"> 
</form> 
<script> 
document.formName.fieldName[2].value = "two"; // set field value 
function see(that) { 
    that.fieldIndexNumber??? 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: (I've fixed it for you.)

Comment: Why do you want the index?

Comment: Good, clear example of what you want! That's relatively rare in someone's first question, nice one.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in the form by looping through the form's collection of `fieldName` elements¹; in fact, you can use `Array`'s [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to do it for you, like this:

```
var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(document.formName.fieldName, that);
```

```js
document.formName.fieldName[2].value = "two"; // set field value 
function see(that) { 
    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(document.formName.fieldName, that);
    console.log(index);
}
```

```html
<form name="formName"> 
<input type=text name=fieldName onFocus="see(this)"> 
<input type=text name=fieldName onFocus="see(this)"> 
<input type=text name=fieldName onFocus="see(this)"> 
</form>
```

`Array.prototype.indexOf` is generic, it doesn't require that you use it on an array, just something array-like. The element collection in a form is array-like, so we can use `indexOf` by using [`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to pass the elements as `this` and the desired element as the first argument.

---

That said, most of the time you don't care what the index of the field is in the form, since you can use `that` to directly reference the field.

---

¹ For anyone with doubts, accessing form fields by name the way the OP did [is specified behavior](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlformelement), see `getter (RadioNodeList or Element) (DOMString name);` in the IDL and the subsequent explanatory note.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional attribute to the input element such as

```
<input data-index="1" onFocus="see(this)">
<input data-index="2" onFocus="see(this)">
<input data-index="3" onFocus="see(this)">
```

Now in your

```
function see(that){
   var indexValue = that.getAttribute("data-index");
}
```

OR

You can also send index to your function like this

```
<input onFocus="see(this, 1)">
<input onFocus="see(this, 2)">
<input onFocus="see(this, 3)">

function see(that, indexValue){}
```

Comment: You can, but then you're creating a maintenance issue, changing the order, adding, removing, etc. without remembering to update the data attribute.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it is true, I never said that there is no work involved in it, it was just one of the options he may choose to use that is all